# MongoDB: findOneAndUpdate seems to be not atomic

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using nodejs + mongodb as a backend for a largely distributed web application. I have a series of events, that need to be in a specific order. There are multiple services generating these events and my application should process and store them as they come in and at any given time I want to have them in the correct order.

I cannot rely on timestamps since javascript only provides timestamps in milliseconds, which is not accurate enough for my case.

I have two collections in my database. One that stores the events and one that stores an index, which represents my eventorder. I have tried using findOneAndUpdate in order to increase my index atomically. This however does not seem to be working.

```
console.log('Adding');
console.log(event.type);

this._db.collection('evtidx').findOneAndUpdate({ id : 'index' }, { $inc: { value : 1 } }, (err, res) => {
    console.log('For '+event.type);
    console.log('Got value: '+res.value.value);

    event.index = res.value.value;
    this._db.collection('events').insertOne(event, (err, evtres) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
});
```

When I check the output of the code above I see:

Adding
Event1
Adding
Event2
Adding
Event3
Adding
Event4
For Event1
Got value: 1
For Event3
Got value: 4
For Event2
Got value: 2
For Event4
Got value: 3

Which concludes to me, that my code is not working atomically.
The events come in in the correct index, but don't have the correct order attached to them after findOneAndUpdate. Could anyone help me out there?

Comment: What do you mean by "atomically"? Also, can you please better describe the use case for this flow? I have a feeling there's got to be a better solution than expecting async javascript events to happen in a certain order.

Comment: The `findOneAndUpdate` is not atomic. Which version of mongodb are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Atomic database operations does not mean that they lock the database while the request is running. Maybe You are getting requests in order but they are not executed in sequential order nor in the backend nor in the database.
What you need to do is read the last document index from the 'events' collection. If its one less then your current request index then insert else wait and retry.
Although this can cause problems if one event fails because of network error or something else. Then Your request processing would stop.